# SQLException when Canceling Async Query

Tags: .net, async-await

Using the new .Net 4.5 Async/Await functionality with a CancellationToken, I get a `SQLException` when I cancel a `ExecuteNonQueryAsync` call, instead of a `OperationCanceledException` (or some other exception that is specific to canceling an operation).  The `SQLException` does say `Operation cancelled by user` at the end of the message.  I expected a more specific exception to be thrown when canceling the operation.  Additionally, how would I create the appropriate Try/Catch handlers to deal with this expected scenario?  I normally would have the `SQLException` as more general failure block, but now I would have to tease out the text of the message to see if this just the user clicking the Cancel button!?  I must be missing something.

Here's a simple VB WinForm app that has two buttons, one to do the Async call, and the other to cancel.  The Try/Catch in the 1st button shows the `SQLException` that is hit when the 2nd button calls the Cancel method.

```
Dim _cts As CancellationTokenSource
Private Async Sub btnLocalTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLocalTest.Click
    _cts = New CancellationTokenSource()
    Dim CancelToken As CancellationToken = _cts.Token
    Using sconn As New SqlConnection("server=(local);database=MyDB;user id=MyUser;password=MyPassword")
        sconn.Open()
        Dim SQL As String = some long running SELECT or INSERT statement
        Try
            Using scmd As New SqlCommand(SQL, sconn)
                scmd.CommandTimeout = 300
                Dim i As Integer = Await scmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(CancelToken)
            End Using
        Catch exCancel As OperationCanceledException
            LogEvent("Query canceled Exception.") ' This error is *not* thrown on Cancel.  
        Catch ex As SqlClient.SqlException
            LogEvent("Error with query. " & ex.Message)  ' This error *is* thrown on Cancel.  Message includes text 'Canceled by user.'
        End Try
        sconn.Close()
        _cts = Nothing
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub btnLocalTestCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLocalTestCancel.Click
    If _cts IsNot Nothing Then
        _cts.Cancel()
    End If
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:** I created a different Async test with the `HttpClient.GetAsync` method that supports cancellation.  When you cancel that task, you can the `OperationCanceledException` exception that I originally expected above.  *So the question remains: what exception should you get when you cancel an Async task?  Or is that dependent upon each method and it's implementation?*

Comment: Use SqlException.Number.

Comment: The `SqlException.Number` = 0.  `SqlException.Errors(1).Number` = 0. Not very helpful.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you found a solution or did you use Message property?

Comment: No, I have not found a consistent Exception class being thrown when canceling Async method.

Comment: Why are you not using OpenAsync() ?

Comment: In general you should get `OperationCanceledException`. I consider `SqlCommand` to be misbehaving here. In my own code I plan to trap this `SqlException` and call `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`in my exception handler.

Answer (score 13):

I "solved" this issue by checking `CancelToken.IsCancellationRequested` in the `Catch ex As SqlClient.SqlException` block.

Answer (score 0):

It is not always as simple as catching an `SqlException`. If you use `Task.Wait()` on the asynchronous task then the `SqlException` will be wrapped inside an `AggregateException`.

A code example that demonstrates this can be found in the ADO.NET section on MSDN, in the article [Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh211418.aspx) (section "Cancelling an Asynchronous Operation").

Documentation for a similar behaviour that is general for the `Task` class is buried in the MSDN article [Task Cancellation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx) (part of the "Task Parallel Library" documentation), although here the `AggregateException` wraps a `TaskCanceledException` (which is derived from `OperationCanceledException`).

Here is a somewhat simplified piece of C# code that shows how I am currently handling cancellation requests with SqlClient:

```
class MyDataProcessor
{
    void ReadSomething(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            // Get the command from somewhere
            DbCommand dbCommand = [...]

            // We don't use await, we manage the Task ourselves
            Task<DbDataReader> task = dbCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(cancellationToken)
            // If cancellation is requested this throws an AggregateException
            task.Wait();

            // Task status should probably be checked here,
            // but this is just sample code
            DbDataReader dbDataReader = task.Result;

            // If cancellation is requested, this throws a straight SqlException
            while (dbDataReader.Read())
            {
                // do something with the data

                // Be nice and check the token. ADO.NET data providers
                // other than SqlClient might not check the token.
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception exception)
        {
            // If it's a cancellation request, transform the SqlException
            // into an OperationCanceledException
            ThrowIfSqlClientCancellationRequested(
                cancellationToken, exception);

            // Re-throw if it's a genuine error
            throw;
        }
    }

    void ThrowIfSqlClientCancellationRequested(
        CancellationToken cancellationToken,
        Exception exception)
    {
        // Check the CancellationToken, as suggested by Anton S in his answer
        if (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            return;
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException sqlException =
            exception as System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException;
        if (null == sqlException)
        {
            AggregateException aggregateException = exception as AggregateException;
            if (null != aggregateException)
                sqlException = aggregateException.InnerException as System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException;
            if (null == sqlException)
                return;
        }
        // Assume that if it's a "real" problem (e.g. the query is malformed),
        // then this will be a number != 0, typically from the "sysmessages"
        // system table 
        if (sqlException.Number != 0)
            return;
        throw new OperationCanceledException();
    }
}
```

I am not very happy with this, it looks brittle, but lacking any official documentation it's the best I could come up with at the moment. The big questions are:

- Will future versions of SqlClient change their cancellation behaviour?
- Are there additional behaviours not covered by the code above?

Comment: Hmm… calling `Task.Wait()` means you block the current thread. If the query runs long enough that you consider it worth having a CancellationToken around, I recommend you also look into `async`/`await`. I would recommend using the synchronous API instead in this case, but I guess it is true that this is the easiest way to cancel a running query even if you aren’t buying into `async`/`await`.

Comment: @binki The `ReadSomething()` function already runs on a separate thread.